# Debugging apache2 errors: exit signal Bus error

Tags: apache-2.4, gdb

I'm hoping someone can help me debug my apache2 errors. For some reasons I'm getting a lot of errors lately on one of my systems:

```
Sat Oct 10 16:49:24.101959 2015] [core:notice] [pid 18380] AH00051: child    pid 2126 exit signal Bus error (7), possible coredump in /tmp/apache-coredumps
[Sat Oct 10 16:50:35.178108 2015] [core:notice] [pid 18380] AH00051: child pid 1971 exit signal Bus error (7), possible coredump in /tmp/apache-coredumps
[Sat Oct 10 16:50:43.188837 2015] [core:notice] [pid 18380] AH00051: child pid 2413 exit signal Bus error (7), possible coredump in /tmp/apache-coredumps
```

I tried debugging with gdb, but I have no clue how to proceed after letting gdp loose on my coredump. This is the gdb output:

```
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.2) 7.7.1
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later   <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from apache2...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//usr/sbin/apache2...done.
done.
[New LWP 2126]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

warning: the debug information found in "/usr/lib/debug//usr/lib/php5/20121212/mysql.so" does not match "/usr/lib/php5/20121212/mysql.so" (CRC mismatch).


warning: the debug information found in "/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/php5/20121212/mysql.so" does not match "/usr/lib/php5/20121212/mysql.so" (CRC mismatch).


 warning: the debug information found in "/usr/lib/debug//usr/lib/php5/20121212/mysqli.so" does not match "/usr/lib/php5/20121212/mysqli.so" (CRC mismatch).


warning: the debug information found in "/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/php5/20121212/mysqli.so" does not match "/usr/lib/php5/20121212/mysqli.so" (CRC mismatch).


warning: the debug information found in "/usr/lib/debug//usr/lib/php5/20121212/pdo_mysql.so" does not match "/usr/lib/php5/20121212/pdo_mysql.so" (CRC mismatch).


warning: the debug information found in "/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/php5/20121212/pdo_mysql.so" does not match "/usr/lib/php5/20121212/pdo_mysql.so" (CRC mismatch).

Core was generated by `/usr/sbin/apache2 -k start'.
Program terminated with signal SIGBUS, Bus error.
#0  0x00007f296c7b87b0 in crc32 () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1
```

Can anyone help me with the next step?

Comment: The next step is to replace the defective hardware.

Comment: Okay, so this points to defective hardware and not a software issue? Bad RAM?